# Problema con int y valores nulos

Tags: java

Tengo un JTable que almacena los valores en un ArrayList de tipo Object y esos datos se envian a una base de datos.Mi problema es que cuando estoy recibiendo los valores tengo que hacer un casteo a los distintos tipos de datos que necesito.Cuando hago el casteo a int y en el JTable no se escribio ningun valor me salta NullPointerException debido a que al no escribir ningun valor se envia un null.Los tipos primitivos no pueden almacenar valores nulos.Como podria solventar este error?

```
cliente.setCantidad((int) lista.get(contador));
        state.setInt(2, cliente.getCantidad());
```

Ahi se ve como se intenta hacer un casteo del valor de la tabla y al ser nulo lanza la excepcion.

Comment: es que si el objeto es null no podes hacer casteo. deberia de verificar
if (list.get(contador)!=null){}

Comment: Primero debes establecer el comportamiento que deseas cuando un campo viene como `null`. Y eso dependerá de la lógica de tu programa. Por lo tanto hay muchas posibilidades, pero sin saber el valor que deseas establecer cuando recibes un `null` es difícil dar respuesta única.

Answer (score 2):

Eso es por como codificaste en el Jtable. Deberias validar en el Jtable, que si no ingreso ningun dato, directamente no llame a ningun metodo y arroje un mensaje indicando eso.

Otra forma de esquivar esos nulls es verificando el tamaño de la lista y a su vez verificar que los objetos no sean null, si es que es una lista de objetos:

```
if(lista.Size() > 0)//con esto válidas que la lista no este vacia
{
   if(Cliente != null)// válidas que el cliente no sea null
   {
       cliente.setCantidad( lista.get(contador));
       state.setInt(2, cliente.getCantidad());
   }
}
```

Si estas usando base de datos y Jtable, te recomiendo que programes en capas y utilices DTO`s para evitar estos problemas. Tambien deberias manejar Strings en los jTable y utilizar los metodos de conversion de cada clase, por ejemplo:

```
Integer.parseInt(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberia de chequear el tipo de datos antes de hacer el casting.
A modo de ejemplo tomando parte de tu código parcial:

```
    Object obj = lista.get(contador);
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        int value = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(obj));
        cliente.setCantidad(value);
        state.setInt(2, cliente.getCantidad());
    }
```